# TrueCrypt: filesystem corruption: is it possible to lose all data at once?

Tags: truecrypt, filesystem-corruption

I read that among various corruption risks is the filesystem corruption, that also affects TrueCrypt volumes, like any other system.I would like to know if it is possible that a corruption in some special small region can lead to lose the entire filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is one critical part in a TrueCrypt volume that has to be present and valid otherwise your data is lost: **The Volume Header**

This is the reason why TrueCrypt has the possibility to back-up this small region and save it somewehere else:

Select **Tools** -> **Backup Volume Header**

The Volume Header is really small it's - the first 512 bytes of the TrueCrypt container.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [truecrypt FAQ](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq), the cipherblock size is 16 bytes, so one bad bit will likely cause the loss of 16 bytes, but not the whole disk.

Comment: so there isn't a more critical zone (for example the root of the filesystem files information), the risk is distributed?